# why Math.Round(66.665d, 2) is 66.67 in c#

Tags: c#

I can understand a = 6.66, but why b is 66.67 instead of 66.66:

```
var a = Math.Round(6.665d, 2);//6.66
var b = Math.Round(66.665d, 2);//66.67
```

Comment: Don't use floating point numbers if you need precision

Comment: Use a decimal instead. Change the d to a m.